# Environment behind window for interior renderings

Tags: rendering, cycles-render-engine, texturing, materials, hdri

I’m mainly interested in architectural visualizations and have also completed a few projects, but there are things that I despair of every time and that is the environment that can be seen through the windows. Should i only use photos or should i model the surroundings for each interior render as well? I am going for a photorealisitc look and would be happy about a tip because i have no idea whats the best way is to do that. I tried HDRs but i only looks ok when the environment is far away. I attach some examples. Thank you!

[image]

[image]

Comment: Hello :). Each of your listed solutions is used - modeling the whole environment, using a HDRI or Blender's *Sky Texture* or simply placing an image texture behind (small) windows. My preferred way: Use and HDRI (for good 360° reflections) and add some real geometry (trees, cars) to make it more customized :).

Comment: @JachymMichal Ok thanks :) so i think the best results are still with models outside the window then just a plane or HDRI

Answer (score 0):

If i understood you right (correct me if i am wrong) you do not want to see the HDRI through the windows, but just use the lights of it, right?

you can do that so: just tap on transparent

[image]

Comment: Hi, no i meant to create the environment outside the window with realistic lighting but thanks for the tip :)

Comment: and why is using HDRI from e.g. HDRI haven not realistic?

Comment: Probably because of perspective. As Yalcin stated in their question, they only look good when there's an HDRI of a large scene like an overview of a city.